# need a regex to get string after 4 occurrences of character from end of string in java

Tags: java, regex

Need a regex which will take string after 4 occurrences of a particular character from a string from end of string.

```
String test = "012.345.Sub_16462_52034247_20151130_.xlsx";
```

Here i need only 16462_52034247_20151130 from `test` string.

Trying to get 16462_52034247_20151130_.xlsx so that i can filter out content before dot. In my case that particular charatcer is "_"

Comment: In your case, the particular character is `_`?

Comment: Step 1: get the requirements clear (why exactly this substring?); Step 2: try to implement it. Step 3 if it does not work, ask here.

Comment: basically i am trying to filter out content after the 4 underscore from end of string (counting from end).

Comment: Do you really need Regex for that? Since you have tagged java, have you taken a look at StringUtils to split your string based on token etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am writing this answer assuming I understood your requirements correctly. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

This answer provides a function to extract the sub-string out of a string based on the following facts:

1. The function should take two inputs i.e. the original String and a search character.
2. Start Index of sub-string should be from the 4th last occurrence of the given search character (say "_").

Here is the code snippet:

```
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        /* Function Call */
        System.out.println(getSubstring("012.345.Sub_16462_52034247_20151130_.xlsx",'_'));
    }

    /**
      * Get Sub-String Function
      * Arguments: Original String, Search Char
      * Output: Filtered Sub-String
    **/

    public static String getSubstring(String originalString, char searchChar) {
        /* Char Occurrence */
        int occurrence = 4;
        /* Last Position */
        int position = originalString.lastIndexOf(searchChar);
        /* Search nth Last Occurrence */
        while (occurrence -- > 1 && originalString.lastIndexOf(searchChar, position-1) != -1)
            position = originalString.lastIndexOf(searchChar, position-1);
        /* Add Additional Filter & Return Sub-String */
        return originalString.substring(position+1,originalString.lastIndexOf('.') - 1);
    }
```

Output:

```
16462_52034247_20151130
```

Comment: i need only 16462_52034247_20151130. here i am trying to get 16462_52034247_20151130_.xlsx using regex so that later i can get 16462_52034247_20151130 from this output. need string after 4th occurrence from right side so that i will get exactly what i want.In your solution if  string is 012.345.Sub_sub_sub_16462_52034247_20151130_.xlsx then it will not work as expected

Comment: Sorry, I made a small mistake. Corrected & Updated the solution.

Comment: i said it will break if we have string 012.345.Sub_sub_sub_16462_52034247_20151130_.xlsx. This is the reason i am counting 4th occurrence from right side.

Comment: This program is doing the same thing. Count the 4th occurrence from the right side. If I give input `012.345.Sub_sub_sub_sub_sub_sub_sub_sub_sub_16462_52034247_20151130_.xlsx` then also I get `16462_52034247_20151130` as output.

Comment: yes,i tried running your previous code.This runs properly.

Answer (score 2):

```
String result = test.subSequence(test.indexOf("_")+1, test.lastIndexOf("_")).toString();
System.out.println(result);
```

output: `16462_52034247_20151130`

Comment: (I didn't downvote) - I just want to comment that you probably want to use .toString() instead of casting

Comment: yes i know that. but this is what the questioner expecting right?

Comment: I think you got downvoted since the question is very unclear and that's why any answer might be wrong (people tend to not-like answers to poorly written questions). Anyway I corrected the vote for ya

Comment: I think that he wants a more general regex. This one only satisfies `test`

Comment: this fails if my string is having _ anywhere else for e.g. 012.345.Sub_teststring_16462_52034247_20151130_.xlsx

Comment: so you already know that text will start with _16462 number only or will it be change?

Comment: Is it sure, you know that output will start with 16462 this number only?

Answer (score 0):

You must search more before asking on SO.

To respond to this question literally, here is one of codes which work:

```
    final String test="012.345.Sub_16462_52034247_20151130_.xlsx";
    final String[] s = test.split("_");
    String result = "";
    for (int i = s.length -4; i < s.length -1; i++) {
        result += s[i] + "_";
    }

    result = result.substring(0, result.length()-1);
    System.out.println(result);
```

Output is: `16462_52034247_20151130`